# python excel reading engine (pandas/read_excel) converting boolean (true/false) to float (1.0/0.0) for incomplete columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

for `pandas.read_excel()`,  booleans in partially filled excel columns are converted to floats as shown in the below comparison:

[image]

As the above shows, when the excel column is completely filled with booleans, the engine performs the conversion as expected. The problem persists for engine = None and 'xlrd' and saving the spreadsheet as 1) Excel Workbook (.xlsx); 2) Excel 97-2003 (.xls); and 3) 5.0/95 workbook.

`pd.__version__ = u'0.18.1'`

`xlrd.__VERSION__ = '1.1.0'`

`Excel Version 1805`

The obvious workaround is to fill the column completely in excel, but this won't work for me.

Comment: Your problem is that you get a column of type float when you have an empty cell? And you want all boolean?

Answer (score 0):

There is likely no direct workaround. Pandas has to make a decision. Since the series can only have one `dtype` it must choose between `object` (which is just a bunch of pointers) or `float` while applying conversion from Boolean to numeric. This may be specific to your Pandas version and/or the Excel reader.

You can post-process using `pd.Series.map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'col2': [1.0, 0.0, np.nan]})

df['col2'] = df['col2'].map({1.0: True, 0.0: False})

print(df)

  col1   col2
0    a   True
1    b  False
2    c    NaN
```

Note the results series will have `object` dtype. This is inefficient as data held in such columns are just a series of pointers (like a Python list).

Comment: Thank you. In general this works, however as I'm dealing with many spreadsheets with many columns (which I don't know the dtype ahead of time) this doesn't help much. Instead, what I've done is a sloppy post-process type detection looking for suspect columns with only dtype=float, values = 1.0 or 0.0. This fails however if the user provides a partial column of just zeros.

Comment: @cefect, In my opinion, you shouldn't use `object` dtype. In other words, choose whether you want Boolean or `float`. If you have genuinely missing values, `float` is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Fill the NaNs to whatever you want, then convert to boolean.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col1=['a', 'b', 'c'], col2=[1.0,0.0,pd.np.NaN]))
df['col2'] = df.col2.fillna(0.0).astype(bool)

df 
  col1   col2
0    a   True
1    b  False
2    c  False
```